# Logic to replace column value in mysql python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-2.7

```
+--- -----+------------+-------------+
|master_id| product_id |products     |
+---------+------------+-------------+
| 0       | 123       | home        |
| 12      | 234       | office      |
| 15      | 456       | home        |
| 0       | 678       | office      |
| 25      | 890       | home        |
| 0       | 145       | office      |
+---+-----------------+--------------+
```

I have this table(only a part of rows are displayed,more than 1000 rows), I want to write a logic , such that, whenever the

master_id = 0 , master_id = product_id

I moved It into pandas dataframe.
now how do I write this logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need pandas for this, you can do it directly via the database.

If you just want to display the records differently:

```sql
SELECT CASE master_id WHEN 0 THEN product_id ELSE master_id END AS master_id,
       product_id,
       products
FROM   mytable
```

If you actually want to update the database, it's even easier:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET    master_id = product_id
WHERE  master_id = 0
```

Comment: can I use select distinct case(...)

Comment: can I use select distinct ?
I want to find the count of products
my query. 
SELECT  DISTINCT CASE master_id WHEN 0 THEN product_id ELSE master_id END AS master_id, count(distinct(product_id) as total_products from mytable group by master_id

Comment: You should group by the same case statement, not the master_id. Using distinct in such a query is possible, but redundant, as the group by takes care of uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select (case when master_id = 0 then product_id else master_id end) as master_id,
       product_id, products
from t;
```

Comment: can I use select distinct case(...)

Comment: can I use select distinct ?
I want to find the count of products
my query. 
select distinct(case when master_id = 0 then product_id else master_id end) as master_id, count(distinct(product_id) as total_products from mytable group by master_id

Comment: @SRingne . . . If you have another question, you should ask it as a question and not in a comment.  But yes, the `distinct` in `select distinct` applies to all expressions in the `select`.  You need to use `group by` to get a count.  If you don't understand that, you should spend some time learning SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a pandas dataframe you can use the [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# initialise dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 12, 15, 0, 25],
                  [123, 234, 456, 678, 890],
                  ['home', 'office', 'home', 'office', 'home']]).T
df.columns = ['master_id', 'product_id', 'products']

# Now do fix master_id
df.master_id = np.where(df.master_id == 0, df.product_id, df.master_id)

# New df:
    master_id   product_id  products
0   123          123          home
1   12           234          office
2   15           456          home
3   678          678          office
4   25           890          home
```